# struts2 and jquery file upload SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I am working on a project that need multiple file upload with the help of jquery and struts.
I have implemented the code but i am having some problems. i have done a lot of search but find nothing to solve this issue.

I am using JQuery-File-Upload 8 and struts 2.

Here is my code

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
       <package name="default" extends="struts-default" >
         <action name="userImage" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.FileUploadAction">
           <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
             <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
             <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg</param>
             <param name="excludeParams">^tag\..*</param>
           </interceptor-ref>
           <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
           <result name="success">SuccessUserImage.jsp</result>
           <result name="input">UserImage.jsp</result>
        </action>       
       </package>
</struts>
```

FileUpload.java

```
package net.viralpatel.struts2;

import java.io.File;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements
        ServletRequestAware {
    private File userImage;
    private String userImageContentType;
    private String userImageFileName;

    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public String execute() {
        try {
            ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
            String path = "MyFolder/";
            //getting the path to where the images will be uploaded
            String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath(path);
            System.out.println(filePath);
            File uploadDir = new File(filePath);
            //if the folder does not exits, creating it
            if (uploadDir.exists() == false) {
                uploadDir.mkdirs();
            }
            FileUtils.copyFile(userImage, new File(uploadDir, userImageFileName));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public File getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public String getUserImageContentType() {
        return userImageContentType;
    }

    public void setUserImageContentType(String userImageContentType) {
        this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
    }

    public String getUserImageFileName() {
        return userImageFileName;
    }

    public void setUserImageFileName(String userImageFileName) {
        this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;

    }
}
```

main.js

```
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin JS Example 8.0.1
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

/*jslint nomen: true, regexp: true */
/*global $, window, navigator */

$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'userImage'
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });
        // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.support.cors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                type: 'HEAD'
            }).fail(function () {
                $('<span class="alert alert-error"/>')
                    .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                    .appendTo('#fileupload');
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, null, {result: result});
        });
    }

});
```

here is the html form part only

index.html

```
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" namespace="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
            <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress information -->
        <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The extended global progress information -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
</form>
```

Here is the error :

```
Jun 17, 2013 11:31:11 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: Error setting expression 'files[]' with value '[Ljava.io.File;@1fb4c2b'
ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: files[] [ognl.ParseException: Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 7.
Was expecting one of:
    ":" ...
    "not" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "~" ...
    "!" ...
    "(" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "#this" ...
    "#root" ...
    "#" ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "@" ...
    "new" ...
    <IDENT> ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    "\'" ...
    "`" ...
    "\"" ...
    <INT_LITERAL> ...
    <FLT_LITERAL> ...
    ]
    at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compile(OgnlUtil.java:225)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:288)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:199)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

INFO: Removing file files[] I:\ashish_datajcr\My_Eclipse_Workspace\.metadata\.me_tcat7\work\Catalina\localhost\FileUpload\upload_7e795db_13f50ab5439__8000_00000005.tmp
Jun 17, 2013 11:31:12 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Removing file files[] I:\ashish_datajcr\My_Eclipse_Workspace\.metadata\.me_tcat7\work\Catalina\localhost\FileUpload\upload_7e795db_13f50ab5439__8000_00000005.tmp
```

Please help me to work it fine. I have spent lot of time working on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifying the **multiple** attribute in your `<input type="file" />` element, the list of files will be probably always sent as a List, even if the file is only one (it will be a List of one element).

In your Action instead, you are defining your file as an single element.

Then you need to change them accoridngly:

change this

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple>
```

to this

```
<input type="file" name="files">
```

(or better use Struts File Tag, like this... always prefer Struts Tags to native HTML tags:)

```
<s:file name="files">
```

To upload one file at time;

otherwise, leave your HTML like that, and change your Action, specifying a List of **File** s, a list of **ContentType** s, a list of **FileName** s, to successfully upload multiple files.

[More info on uploading multiple files with Struts2 from the official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-UploadingMultipleFilesusingLists)